# Access Report -- Set ControlSource Dynamically

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

I have a scenario here with my MS Access Report where the ControlSource of a specific text box can vary depending on the value of a field bound to that report.

For example:

`If VALUE = 1 then
     Me.txtFeesAndExpenses.ControlSource = "The following fees for this specific scenario are " & FEE_VALUE
End if`

OR

`If VALUE = 2 then
    Me.txtFeesAndExpenses.ControlSource = "The following fees for this OTHER specific scenario are " & FEE_VALUE
End if`

I'm having trouble with where I should place this code on my report so that the proper value is bound to the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn'it easier to use calculated field and set such `ControlSource` in the design mode:

```
 ="The following fees for " & SWITCH(VALUE=1,"THIS",value=2,"OTHER",true," ERROR ")
    & " specific scenario are " & FEE_VALUE
```

Comment: Good point @4dmonster. I put it an example there, but I really have a paragraph to work with. Probably doesn't make a difference as far as performance goes?

Comment: @mntyguy if you care about performance, you probably should put it in the query(Recordsource of the report)  `"The following fees for " & SWITCH(VALUE=1,"THIS",value=2,"OTHER",true," ERROR ")
    & " specific scenario are " & FEE_VALUE AS [TEXT_for_FEE] ` and then set `ControlSource` to just field `TEXT_for_FEE`